# Calling specific for_each outputs

Tags: terraform

I'm just starting to use for_each loops and from what I understand for_each is different than count in the sense that count indexes numerically for outputs aws_transfer_key.transfer_key[1] vs for_each outputs aws_transfer_key.transfer_key["value"].

How do I call the output of a for_each value later on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `resource` or `data` block with the `count` argument set appears in expressions as a list, which is why you can access its instances with `[0]`, `[1]`, etc.

Similarly, a `resource` or `data` block with the `for_each` argument set appears in expressions as a *map*, so you can access its instances with `["foo"]`, `["bar"]`, etc.

In both cases the collection is of objects conforming to the resource type schema, so you can follow that with `.attribute` syntax to access individual attributes.

So first take the resource type and name, `aws_transfer_key.transfer_key`, which is a map. Then `["value"]` to access the instance you want from the map. Then `.foo` to access the "foo" attribute. All together, that's `aws_transfer_key.transfer_key["value"].foo`.

If you want to access *all* of the "foo" attributes across all of the instances, you can project the map of objects into a map of strings using a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions):

```
{ for k, v in aws_transfer_key.transfer_key : k => v.foo }
```

Comment: Thats what I thought, but when I attempted to call the value ```aws_transfer_key.transfer_key["value"].foo```. I receive an error: "Resource aws_s3_bucket.ancb must be indexed with a number value."

Comment: Just figured out why I was receiving that error. When I was creating the resource that I wanted to call I was using count (from a previous deployment). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From the example [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html)

```
resource "aws_security_group" "example" {
  name = "example" # can use expressions here

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.service_ports
    content {
      from_port = ingress.value
      to_port   = ingress.value
      protocol  = "tcp"
    }
  }
}
```

You reference the name of the dynamic block, in this case it's an `ingress`.